# How can I exclude a list of strings in a spreadsheet query just like "not in" works in SQLanguage?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a query function and I want to exclude a list fo strings.
In SQL could be:

```
"SELECT A, B WHERE B NOT IN ('value1, 'value2')"
```

But cannot make it work in my Googlesheet...

Answer (score 0):

If you are you looking to *return Columns A & B where the values in B are not “value1” or “value2”* the formula would be:

```
=QUERY(A:B,”
   SELECT A,B
   WHERE B <> ‘value1’ 
     AND B <> ‘value2’”,1)
```

If the values you want to exclude are stored in cells (say `C1` & `D1`) instead of hardcoded you’d use:

```
=QUERY(A:B,”
   SELECT A,B
   WHERE B <> “&C1&” 
     AND B <> “&D1&””,1)
```